# Which Java exception should I throw when I cannot delete a resource because it's being used?

Tags: java, rest, exception, http-delete

I have a RESTful web application with an endpoint that allows the user to delete a particular resource by providing its id:

`DELETE /rules/{id}`

In some cases, one `rule` may reference another `rule`. If `Rule A` references `Rule B`, and a user attempts to delete `Rule B`, I'm not allowing that.

In my server code, I'd like the delete method in my manager (one layer deeper than the REST method) to throw an exception when a rule cannot be deleted because it's being referenced by another rule. My REST method will then have a catch block for this exception and formulate the appropriate HTTP response.

What is an appropriate exception for my manager method to throw in this case?

Comment: Would you consider it a fit for an `IllegalStateException`? I'm not sure in this context if you consider it to be an "illegal state" or not.

Comment: Just make your own exception. `public class RuleDeleteException extends Exception`

Comment: @Carcigenicate I guess that's workable if you consider "In Use" as a state. It's a good thought...

Comment: @j.seashell Yes, that's always an option. I was hoping there was a standard exception for cases like these.

Comment: What J. said, but I think I would consider having `RuleDeleteException` extend `IOException` instead of just `Exception`.  Given it's a REST app, it might be easier in the long run to have everything be an IO exception if you want to make a high level common error handler.

Comment: I would say `IllegalStateException`, but that is an unchecked exception, meaning it shouldn't be used to indicate a transient problem (I.e. it might succeed if you try exactly the same thing later). A checked exception is more appropriate.